# I want to iterate an array inside a json in table column through angular

Tags: angularjs, json, html

I have a json and inside this json there is an array that I want to iterate in `<td>`.
My functionality is like I have to create a table based on user input. User provides input for number of rows, input columns and output columns. So I have three arrays i.e $rootScope.input_columns, $rootScope.output_columns and $rootScope.rows which contain data provided by user to create the table. Now in input_columns there's an array which contains some information which I need to show on row cell. But with my current code it is giving me blank row.

This is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp');

app.controller('myController2', ['$scope', '$rootScope',function($scope, $rootScope){
var inputcol=[];
            $rootScope.input_col=$scope.no_of_input;
            $rootScope.output_col=$scope.no_of_output;
            $rootScope.row=$scope.no_of_row;
            for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.input_col;i++){
                inputcol.push({
                    id: inputcol.length,
                    dropped: false,
                    dataType:'',
                    name:'',
                    type:'input',
                    path:'',
                    rowCellValue:[],
                    rowCellValueOutput:[]
                });
            }$rootScope.input_columns=inputcol;//here i get input_columns json, Similarly json are made for output_columns and rows
            $scope.statementSelected = function(branch, selected_branches) {
        if(branch.selected) {
            for(var i = 0; i < $rootScope.input_columns.length; i++) {  
//Here i add an array inside input_columns.rowCellValue     $rootScope.input_columns[i].rowCellValue.push($rootScope.rows[i].rowCellValue);
                    }
})
```

Adding the structure of input_columns

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows"><!--It iterates on row json -->
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <!--Here i want that in row cells input_columns.rowCellValue data gets populate on row cell for input column -->
        <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns.rowCellValue">{{(col == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.split("/")[3])}}</td>
        <!--Here i want that in row cells output_columns.rowCellValueOutput data gets populate on row cell for output column -->
        <td ng-repeat="col in output_columns.rowCellValueOutput" ng-click="openDialog($event)">{{(col == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.split("/")[3])}}</td>              
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I am getting blank rows
[image]

Please can anyone help me in this task. Is there an issue that I haven't iterated input_columns so i am not getting input_columns.rowCellValue values. How can I get the values of input_columns.rowCellValue in table columns? Is there anyway that I can iterate input_columns and output_columns arrays in trouble tag with rows array?

Comment: There is no `rows` array in your controller scope. Why are you using `$rootScope` in the controller to store controller data?

Comment: Rows array is same as input_column array.Yes I am using $rootScope for storing controller data and for using this data in different controller too

Comment: Is there anything like nested ng-repeat? Can I iterate rows,input-column and output_column array in tr tag?

Comment: I am using input_column for making input columns and output_columns for making output columns, with rows array I get the number of rows user wants to create.. But now I want to set some data in table cells which I have stored in input_column.rowCellValue and output_column.rowCellValueOutput. Now I am facing issue in iterating this arrays and setting value.

Comment: Better to use a service to share data across controllers than use $rootScope

Comment: Ok,does am not able to get rowCellValue value because it is stored in $rootScope? I am able to get $rootScope.input_column.name value. I thought that may be there would be some other way to get array value inside a object

Answer (score 0):

`rows` array and all other arrays in your code are in `$rootScope`. But code which executes in your view is also looking in `$scope` which is assigned to this view with specified controller. If you want to use your data through `$rootScope` you should use `$parent` in your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $parent.rows">
```

and the same way in all other places

Comment: you aren't considering that `$scope` inherits from `$rootScope` and view always has access to $rootScope

Comment: Yes, but as I know and saw earlier its better to use `$parent`  in views to direct and faster access

Comment: huh? It's the same thing and same object reference. There is nothing `faster` about it